# Defining xlim when plotting multiple year data on same axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot several years of data over the same axes. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596714) is helpful but I can't seem to define `xlim`. MWE is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr

data15 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], index=pd.date_range(start='2015-01',end='2016-01',freq='M'), columns=['2015'])
data16 = pd.DataFrame([5,4,3,2,1], index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01',end='2016-06',freq='M'), columns=['2016'])

data15['month'] = data15.index.to_series().dt.strftime('%b')
data16['month'] = data16.index.to_series().dt.strftime('%b')

ax = data16.plot(x='month', y='2016')
ax = data15.plot(x='month', y='2015', ax=ax)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels()[::2], visible=False)

ax.set_xlim(data16.month[0], data16.month[-1])
plt.show()
```

It only wants to show the first two data points no matter how I change `xlim`. How do I fix this?

[image]

The graph without `set_xlim` is

[image]

so the `ax.set_xlim(data16.month[0], data16.month[-1])` line should show only the points between `Jan` and `May`.

Comment: matplotlib and pandas often have difficulties interacting when the objects are only implicitly declared, especially when it comes to datetime objects. But here you mix a categorical pandas plot (df["month"]) with matplotlib's Dates locator. What should the labels show? Is there always just one data point per month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still unclear what the conditions of the dataframes are but mixing pandas matplotlib convenience wrapper with higher-end matplotlib functions often creates problems. Assuming that exactly one monthly datapoint per dataframe exists, you could extract the month number and relabel the x-axis with the month name:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import calendar

data15 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], index=pd.date_range(start='2015-01',end='2016-01',freq='M'), columns=['2015'])
data16 = pd.DataFrame([5,4,3,2,1], index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01',end='2016-06',freq='M'), columns=['2016'])

#generating column with month number
data15['month'] = data15.index.to_series().dt.month                                               
data16['month'] = data16.index.to_series().dt.month

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(data15['month'], data15['2015'], label="2015")
ax.plot(data16['month'], data16['2016'], label="2016")

#setting x-ticks 1-12 with corresponding month names
ax.set_xticks(range(1, 13), [calendar.month_abbr[i] for i in range(1, 13)])
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Alternatively, you can create datetime objects that are all set to the first of the corresponding month of an arbitrary year:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data15 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], index=pd.date_range(start='2015-01',end='2016-01',freq='M'), columns=['2015'])
data16 = pd.DataFrame([5,4,3,2,1], index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01',end='2016-06',freq='M'), columns=['2016'])

#generating datetime objects keeping only the month
#while setting day/year to arbitrary values so that the curves align
data15['month'] = data15.index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(day=1, year=2000)                                                
data16['month'] = data16.index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(day=1, year=2000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(data15['month'], data15['2015'], label="2015")
ax.plot(data16['month'], data16['2016'], label="2016")

#formatting monthly x-axis ticks showing only the month name
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

The output looks the same but you still have datetime objects albeit with an arbitrary year and day.

And assuming that you might want to compare many years, you could embed the first approach in a function like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import calendar

data15 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], index=pd.date_range(start='2015-01',end='2016-01',freq='M'), columns=['2015'])
data16 = pd.DataFrame([5,4,3,2,1], index=pd.date_range(start='2016-01',end='2016-06',freq='M'), columns=['2016'])

#collecting all dataframes to plot
plot_list = [data15, data16]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def plot_line(df):
    #this assumes that the data to plot will always be in the first column
    col = df.columns[0]
    ax.plot(df.index.to_series().dt.month, df[col], label=col)                                              

for item in plot_list:
    plot_line(item)

ax.set_xticks(range(1, 13), [calendar.month_abbr[i] for i in range(1, 13)])
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```